# How to get unique value in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to get unique values from this array and save them in the table `$tab = array('one','two','tree');` ?

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
    array(1) {
     ["tagi"]=>
        string(183) "photoshop, grafika, animacje,photoshop, grafika, animacje,photoshop, grafika, animacje,photoshop, grafika, animacje,photoshop, grafika, animacje,photoshop, grafika, animacje, tutorial"
  }
  [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tagi"]=>
        string(38) "photoshop, grafika, animacje, poradnik"
  }
}
```

Comment: This will need some further explanation, also, what have you tried?

Comment: You go through the array and filter it. That's how.

Comment: On the array elements is string. In this string has is repeated words. He wants to take from string only unique words across the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $mainArray = array(2)... , try this code:

```
$mainString = "";
foreach($mainArray as $array){
  foreach($array as $row){
    $mainString .= $row;
  } $mainString .= ", ";
}

$tempArray = explode(", ", $mainString);

$finishArray = array_unique($tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-unique.php). This function takes one array as argument and generates a new array with distinct values of the argument array.

Comment: along with `array_merge` on all the `tagi` values, this is correct.

Comment: and `explode` to get words

Answer (score 0):

How to remove empty lines ?

```
array(6) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "photoshop"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "grafika"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "animacje"
      [12]=>
      string(8) "tutorial"
      [16]=>
      string(8) "poradnik"
      [17]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
```

Comment: to remove empty elements in the array, try this code:                                  1)  $new_array = array_filter($old_array, function($element) {
    return !empty($element);
});                                                                                                                               2) $new_array = array_diff($old_array, array(''));